# Is it possible to use FTP protocol for instant messaging?

Tags: ftp, network-programming, network-protocols, instant-messaging

Is it possible to use FTP protocol for an instant messaging software instead of other common protocols?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Give us some background.

Comment: I am creating my own IM app. I asked because of curiosity

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for asking questions out of curiosity. SO is for asking about specific programming problems.

Comment: It's a programming problem. But you do not have any proper answer

Answer (score -2):

It is possible to build some kind of IM app with the FTP protocol but it would be painful, slower than others and probably insecure.

You might want to consider

XMPP is the open standard for messaging and presence
https://xmpp.org/